Getting Error: Internal error. (Error code: 13) Earth Engine when exporting to my cloud bucket
I'm using this to export a region to my cloud bucket in Google Cloud
var convertedDataset = H2017static.select('constant').multiply(1000).int16()

var visualization = {
  bands: "constant",
  min: 0,
  max: 1000, // Adjust the maximum value based on your data range
  palette: ['0c0c0c', '071aff', 'ff0000', 'ffbd03', 'fbff05', 'fffdfd']
};


//Map.centerObject(convertedDataset);

Map.addLayer(convertedDataset, visualization, 'Human modification');

// Define an export region.
var exportRegion = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([115.0, 4.0, 127.0, 21.0]);
Map.centerObject(exportRegion);
Map.addLayer(exportRegion, {}, 'exportRegion');

// Export the visualization image as map tiles.
Export.map.toCloudStorage({
  // All tiles that intersect the region get exported in their entirety.
  // Clip the image to prevent low resolution tiles from appearing outside
  // of the region.
  image: convertedDataset.clip(exportRegion),
  description: 'ghm_2017',
  bucket: 'impact_map2',
  scale: 1000,
  region: exportRegion,
  
});

But I keep on receiving this error in my Earth Engine console:

ID: CCOU2LYIGRHEOKAKRHPPBWN5
Phase: Failed
Runtime: 31s (started 2024-04-08 15:34:28 +0800)
Attempted 5 times
Priority: 100 (default)
Error: Internal error. (Error code: 13)

